# Why get call to node.js server isn't getting any answer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am sending a simple get request (without any params) through chrome/postman When and after 2 minutes I  got an error messsage.

I expected to get an answer "cannot get" on sending get request to `localhost:3030`
I expect to get the JSON file on my db when I send a get request to `localhost:3030/api/task`
In both cases I get the "loading /thinking" circle and nothing happens.

Error messsages (after 2 minutes of "loading"):
On chrome - After 2 minutes - I got  " This site can't be reached" And On Postman "Could not get response

I wrote a console.log on the task controller file and it's even not reaching there.

I am attaching the server.js file. I suspect something is wrong there. I don't want to overload this question.

```js
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require('path')
// const expressSession = require('express-session')

const app = express()
const http = require('http').createServer(app)

// const session = expressSession({
//         secret: 'coding is amazing',
//         resave: false,
//         saveUninitialized: true,
//         cookie: { secure: false }
//     })
//Express App Config
app.use(express.json())
//app.use(session)

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')))
} else {
  const corsOptions = {
    origin: ['http://127.0.0.1:8080', 'http://localhost:8080', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000', 'http://localhost:3000'],
    credentials: true
  }
  app.use(cors(corsOptions))
}
const taskRoutes = require('./api/task/task.routes')
//const { connectSockets } = require('./services/socket.service')

// routes
const setupAsyncLocalStorage = require('./middlewares/setupAls.middleware')
app.all('*', setupAsyncLocalStorage)

// app.get('/api/setup-session', (req, res) => {
//     req.session.connectedAt = Date.now()
//     console.log('setup-session:', req.sessionID);
//     res.end()
// })

app.use('/api/task', taskRoutes)
//connectSockets(http, session)
//connectSockets(http);


// Make every server-side-route to match the index.html
// so when requesting http://localhost:3030/index.html/car/123 it will still respond with
// // our SPA (single page app) (the index.html file) and allow vue/react-router to take it from there
// app.get('/**', (req, res) => {
//     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
// })

const logger = require('./services/logger.service')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3030
http.listen(port, () => {
  logger.info('Server is running on port: ' + port)
})
```

Comment: does anything show up in the server logs by any chance?

Comment: On chrome - After 2 minutes - I got  " This site can't be reached" And On Postman "Could not get response

Comment: Is your middleware behaving correctly? Also, I've never seen express.static or cors be determined by the environment, are you sure that's correct? I'd remove more code until I works and see what's mucking it up.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible reasons:

1. You aren't going to `localhost:3030`.
2. `process.env.PORT` is being set to something other than 3030.

Once you check these, it should go away.